# Filter related objects Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Imagine such models in Django:

```
class Organisation(Model):
    ...

class Guest(Model):
    organisation = ForeignKey(Guest, CASCADE, 'guests')

class Booking(Model):
    guest = ForeignKey(Guest, CASCADE, 'bookings')
    start_date = DateField()
    end_date = DateField()
```

Using Django Rest Framework it is needed to perform a endpoint for

- all organisations to be listed
- all guests to be listed
- bookings to be filtered agains start_date and listed

Sample of response:

```
"Organizations": [
    {
        ...,
        "Guests": [
            {
                ...,
                "Bookings": [
                     {...},
                     {...}
                ]
            },
            {
                ...,
                "Bookings": [
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        ...,
        "Guests": [
            {
                ...,
                "Bookings": [
                     {...},
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

So, as you can see, I need all Organisations and Guests to be present, not only those who have Bookings.

What is the optimal way to perform that?

UPD:

Serializers used:

```
class BookingShortSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'start_date',
            'guest',
        )


class GuestBookingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bookings = BookingShortSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Guest
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'name',
            'bookings',
        )


class OrganizationShortSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    guests = GuestBookingsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = (
            'pk',

            'public_name',
            'internal_name',

            'guests',

            'order',
        )
```

ViewSet used (no filtering now):

```
class OrganizationBookingsViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    ordering = 'order'

    serializer_class = OrganizationShortSerializer

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet:
        return Organization.objects.all()
```

Comment: can you add the serializers and view class?

Comment: Serialisers and ViewSet added

Comment: If you are not filtering the `Organization QuerySet`, you'll get the expected result

Comment: I need not to filter Organisation, but filter nested in it Booking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this approach using **SerializerMethodField** solves the task. Should it be considered as a good solution, or not?

```
class GuestBookingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bookings = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Guest
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'name',
            'bookings',
        )

    def get_bookings(self, guest):
        date = self.context.['request'].query_params['start_date__gte']
        bookings = guest.bookings.filter(start_date__gte=date).all()
        serializer = BookingShortSerializer(bookings, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```